# Use two different mail servers for a single domain

Tags: email, smtp, pop3

sorry for my english, I have used Google Translate.

I have a Arsys host (an ISP host from Spain), which gives me 50 email accounts with 6GB of storage each.
I have about 6 accounts of those who need more than 6GB each, since they use much mail.

My problem is that I would like, that of the 50 accounts, who no longer need 6GB stay in Arsys, as the price goes into the budget for the storage they provide. But other accounts using more than 6GB use another mail server that offers apart eg. Amazon ... that even if you pay more you get up to 50GB of email

I've been watching Workmail Amazon, Google Apps for Bussiness, Microsoft Exchange, Office 365 ... and another that I do not remember because they offer mail service for businesses. It is quite out of my budget if I want to migrate all your mail accounts. So I just want some loose.

What I want to do is, if there is a DNS configuration to try a mail accounts (<6GB) to the mail server and the other Arsys (> 6GB) other payment server with more storage.

I do not know if I've explained.

Thank you.

Comment: You are much more likely to invest more money into troubleshooting problems caused by the configuration you suggest, than by simply investing a couple of Euros per month into a bigger email plan. My advice would be to get a bigger plan or move to another company with higher quotas.

Comment: This is not how SMTP works. MX records are configured on a domain-wide basis; there are no mechanisms for sub-dividing as you suggest.

Comment: @TomTom You have no way of knowing what the financial situation of this company is. Please refrain from making conjectures. Just answer the question and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. DNS wise. Normal approach is one server forwards specific accounts to another server. Via settings on the one authoritative server that gets all emails.